# Looking for a good Delphi unicode string library

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Any suggestion for a good unicode string library for Delphi 2010? Such thing as class that would contain a collection of independent functions, basically an encapsulation of functions that manipulate strings (ex: Trimlike, Character removal, Positional, Sub-string, Compare, Informational, Case, Replacement, Manipulation functions etc. ).

Thanks

Comment: You know that from D2009 up, Delphi is fully unicode-capable? So you can just use the functions provided by the RTL.

Comment: yes i know but i have to distribute freely the library source. i will be using the soft gems and the jcl libraries. thank.

Comment: Of course you can't redistribute Delphi source code, but whoever has Delphi has that library. AFAIK even the GPL excludes the compiler standard libraries from its requirements.

Answer (score 10):

What about SysUtils and StrUtils? They contain many String manipulation functions.
And if those functions aren't enough you could try the JclStrings unit from the JCL - JEDI Code Library (not to be confused with the JVCL - JEDI Visual Component Library).

Comment: thank you - i cannot use the delphi source code because i need to distribute freely the library. jclstrings is fine.

Comment: @volvox: You keep saying that about distributing the source, but the people who will use your code will *have* the source - they come standard with the Delphi product and have been reproduced for the most part in Free Pascal. Standard libraries are specifically excluded from the licensing requirements of the GPL and other OSS licenses.

Answer (score 3):

Mike Lischke has an excellent Unicode library at [Soft Gems](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=23&Itemid=33).  It hasn't been updated for Delphi 2009/2010 yet, but it was already working with WideStrings/WideChars, so it should be a pretty trivial port.